# Opennebula Sunston user oneadmin password

Tags: linux, opennebula

Opennebula 4.2.0

I accidentally deleted the file /var/lib/one/.one/one_auth, so I lost the the oneadmin user password. How can I get it back or init the oneadmin password?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the manual at i.e. http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Cloud_OpenNebula#Setting_up_authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of lost password you can use another user in oneadmin group to change the lost password:

```
    $ oneuser passwd --sha1 oneadmin 'newpassword'
```

Or change the password directly in the database:

- Stop OpenNebula daemons (this is needed as some data is cached).
- Connect to the database and get the body of `oneadmin` user:

  ```
  select body from user_pool where name='oneadmin';
  ```
- You will get an xml document with user data. The value you have to change is `password`. Make sure the password is hashed with sha1. You can do it with this command:

  ```
  $ echo -n 'newpassword' | openssl sha1
  ```
- Update the table with the edited xml:

  ```
  update user_pool set body='<edited xml>' where name='oneadmin';
  ```

Now you can change your credentials and start OpenNebula again:

```
    $ echo "oneadmin:new_password" > ~/.one/one_auth
    $ one start
```